# ¿Qué es un variante correcto de frase "Ya algunos días me (doler) la cabeza"?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Primero, pido perdón por mi español.

1. Ya algunos días me ***duela*** la cabeza.
2. Ya algunos días me ***duele*** la cabeza.

¿Si debemos usar `el modo subjuntivo` en esta oración?
¿Si la parte ***ya algunos días*** nos hace usarlo?
Y explique Ud. si es posible.

Más vale si contesta Ud. en español.

Gracias.

Comment: "Ya algunos días" parece incorrecto, no estoy seguro de lo que quiere decir. ¿Puede agregar contexto, o explicar qué quiere decir? ¿Quiere afirmar que Ud. tiene dolor de cabeza desde algunos días en el pasado? ¿O que a veces (algunos días, aislados) tiene dolor de cabeza?

Comment: What is the idea you want to express in english? i.e. please post the english version of what you need, so it's easier to translate.

Comment: @leonbloy y DiegoDD si tienen Uds. interés, lean por favor los comentarios de abajo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas opciones son correctas, pero probablemente ninguna de las dos sea lo que usted quiere decir.

"Ya algunos días me duela la cabeza" se utilizaría como complemento de otra oración, con "Ya" significando "aunque":

"Continuaré yendo a mi trabajo ya algunos días me duela la cabeza." -> "Continuaré yendo a mi trabajo aunque algunos días me duela la cabeza".

"Ya algunos días me duele la cabeza" puede tener significado tanto comparativo como de tiempo:

Comparativa: "Ya algunos días me duele la cabeza como para que encima vengas tú con tus problemas".

De tiempo: "Ya algunos días me duele la cabeza de lo viejo que soy." -> "Ya soy tan viejo que algunos días me duele la cabeza".

Comment: Entonces, si utilizar esta oración independientemente, hay que decir **duele**, ¿verdad?

Comment: ¿Utilizada independientemente? Ya ha visto que en todos los ejemplos se utiliza junto a una oración principal o se complementa una parte. Otra cosa sería "Algunos días me duele la cabeza". Si me dice su idioma materno sería más fácil ayudarle.

Comment: Sí, he visto. Pero en mi idioma (ruso) es posible utilizarla independientemente. Puede ser así el significado de la frase sea más claro: "Durante unos días (p. ej.: anteayer, ayer y hoy) ...". Por ejemplo esta frase puede ser una respuesta a pregunta: ¿Cómo te sientes?

Comment: @Román "Durante unos días me duele la cabeza." no sería correcto. Debería utilizar "Durante unos días me ha dolido la cabeza" en pretérito perfecto (si ya no le duele) o "Durante unos días me dolió la cabeza." en pretérito imperfecto (si terminó pero le puede volver a doler por la misma causa). Si le dolió y ahora le sigue doliendo, se utilizaría también el pretérito perfecto.

Comment: ...o me pone la frase exacta en ruso y tratamos de traducirla.

Comment: Textualmente: "Уже несколько дней у меня болит голова". O si decir más como los rusos (otro órden de palabras): "(У меня) Голова болит уже несколько дней". Se sobrentiende que y ahora mísmo la me duele. En ruso el órden de las palabras es muy libre y puede decir misma frase de tal o cual manera.

Comment: "Уже несколько дней у меня болит голова" -> "Llevo varios días con dolor de cabeza"

Comment: "Me lleva doliendo la cabeza (ya) varios días" o "Desde hace días me duele la cabeza"

Comment: @Envite ¿Y ésta oración sobrentiende que la cabeza me duele ahora mísmo?